# MSSQL2008 Backup of Log does not reduce log size

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, backup

I did a full backup of my database in MSSQL2008  and then performed a backup of the Log. I expected the transaction log file to change in size, but when I checked the file on disk, it remains the same. Note: Database is in FULL recovery mode. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server will not automatically shrink the physical size of the log after a backup.

Continually shrinking and regrowing the log after each backup would cause unnecessary performance issues (growing requires zeroing out the newly allocated space).

After the transaction log backup the log can be automatically truncated (not shrunk) which just marks any no longer required VLFs as available to be over written.

Comment: Martin is there a advised size ratio for your .mdf and .ldf files ?? say if I have a 30GB .mdf file what will be the best size for .ldf file ??

Comment: @M.Ali - No. See [My database is X GB, how big should my log be?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cindygross/archive/2011/03/01/my-database-is-x-gb-how-big-should-my-log-be.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the link very interesting and informational Cheers.

Comment: So MartinSmith it means that I do not need to do anything else on the physical log file? I was worried because the log is about 60GB against a 15GB database and this does not "look good" because I should have begun the backup procedure long before the logs got to this size.

Comment: @stingray_ Well if this 60GB is unusually high you could do a one off shrink task to bring it down to something more representative of what you actually need. But shrinking the log file as a regular practice is not recommended.